# nmcli cloned-mac-address for *all* connections

Tags: wireless-networking, mac-address, networkmanager, spoofing

How can I clone the mac address on my linux system using the `nmcli` command such that it's cloned for *all* wifi connections?

I'm having issues with Network Manager overriding the mac address that I set with `macchanger`. I found documentation online with how to define a mac address using `nmcli` on a per-connection (ie: specific SSID connection), but the documentation is strikingly absent for how to set the mac address globally for *all* connections.

Please tell me how I define the mac address for a given wifi interface using `nmcli` globally, such that all subsequent wifi connections use the given mac address.

Answer (score 4):

Defaults can be specified in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`, see [NetworkManager.conf(5)](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/network-manager/NetworkManager.conf.5.en.html).

```
[connection]
ethernet.cloned-mac-address=<addr>
wifi.cloned-mac-address=<addr>
```

Note that some defaults only apply to *newly created* connection profiles. For existing profiles, you'll have to set the address manually (via `nmcli` or by editing the "connection" files under /etc).

> this doesn't answer the question of how to set the global default with the nmcli command

You *cannot* set the global default with nmcli.

As documented in the manual page, if you want to automatically manage this configuration, you can have it as a separate file `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/<name>.conf`. As it is dedicated to your bash script, you can simply overwrite it instead of carefully editing.

Comment: thank you, but this doesn't answer the question of how to set the global default with the `nmcli` command. Using the command is much more robust pragmatically. Dealing with files is a far more complex approach for a BASH script than executing an `nmcli` command. Is it possible to do this with `nmcli` without modifying config files?